# Retrieving objects from firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working on simple program - I create objects of products and then I count their calories.

I want to count sum of all calories of my products.

I've created a method, allowing me to save data properly in Firebase, but I got stuck while retrieving them:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TotalViewController: UIViewController {

    var products = [Products]()

    @IBOutlet weak var calotyCounter: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DataService.dataService.PRODUCT_BASE.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            print(snapshot.value)

            self.products = []

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots {

                    if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        let key = snap.key

                        let product = Products(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)


                    }
                }
            }

            self.updateCalory()

        })


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func updateCalory() {

        var CaloryArray: [Int] = []

        for product in products {

            CaloryArray.append(Int(product.productCalories))

        }

        print (CaloryArray)

        calotyCounter.text? = String(CaloryArray.reduce(0, combine: +))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

I got an empty array, instead of array of objects callory value.

Here is my model of Products.I made it through dictionary

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Products {

    private var _productName: String!

    private var _productCalories: Int!


    var productName: String {

        return _productName

    }

    var productCalories: Int {

        return _productCalories
    }

    init(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {


        if let calories = dictionary["calories"] as? Int {

            self._productCalories = calories
        }

        if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {

            self._productName = name
        }


    }


}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have only initiated the empty array of `products` in viewDidLoad()

```
self.products = []
```

and not assigning any thing to it anywhere. thats why you are getting the empty array.

and on `updateCalory()` method you are looping on empty array (array with zero items)

**EDIT 1**

you must append the `product` i.e

```
let product = Products(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)
```

to your `products` array in loop. like this

```
for snap in snapshots {

                if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key

                    let product = Products(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)
                    self. products.append(product) // add this line

                }
            }
```